# Implementing pagination in USSD code using core php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a USSD code that will display menus. However, the menus cannot be displayed in their entirety on the phone's screen. The menus are dynamically fetched from the database  So I want to display the first 4 menus as shown below;

````
   1. coconut
   2. mango
   3. pineapple
   4. Pear
   5. Melon
   6. Banana```

```This is how I want it

First Menu 
   1. coconut
   2. mango
   3. pineapple
   99. Next

second menu
   4. Pear
   5. Melon
   6. Banana
   00. Back
````

if Im echoing the menus from this array.(or from the db)

```
$menu = array("cocnut", "mango", "Tpineapple", "pear","melon","Banana");

foreach($menu as $menu){

echo $menu;

}
```

Comment: array_chunk() for example and its elements will be your pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, you are actually showing 3 items per page with the next and previous menu items to handle navigation. To achieve that you will need to have a store of the user's selected index on your server.

So for the solution I have seperated the code into 3 functions.

To run the solution, refer to the test cases.

## Pagination

The function takes the input from the user and the current index saved on your server per request.

```
function pagination($input, $currentIndex)
{
    $menu = array("Coconut", "Mango", "Pineapple", "Pear","Melon","Banana");
    $pages =  array_chunk($menu, 3); // Split array into chunks of 3 items
    $index = $currentIndex; // Current Index Must To Stored Upon Every USSD Request in your database or session.

    if($input == 99)
    {
        $index++;
        displayMenu($pages[$index], $index);
    }
    else if($input == 00)
    {
        $index--;
        displayMenu($pages[$index], $index);
    }
    else if($input != "")
    {
        selectItem($input, $pages[$index]);
    }
    else
    {
        displayMenu($pages[$index], $index);
    }
}
```

## Display Menu

```
function displayMenu($items, $index)
{
    //Show Menu
    echo "Page ".($index+1)."<br>";
    foreach($items as $key => $item)
    {
        echo ($key + 1).'. '.$item."<br>";
    }
}
```

## Select Item

```
function selectItem($input, $menu)
{
    if(array_key_exists(($input-1), $menu))
    {
        echo "Selected Item: " . $menu[($input-1)];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid Selection";
    }
}
```

## Test Cases

```
echo pagination("", 0)."<br>"."<br>";

echo pagination(99, 0)."<br>"."<br>";

echo pagination(2, 0)."<br>"."<br>";

echo pagination(3, 1)."<br>"."<br>";

echo pagination(00, 1)."<br>"."<br>";

echo pagination(00, 2)."<br>"."<br>";
```